# React Native Flex not applying to elements

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-paper

I'm using react-native-paper trying to center elements using Flex:

```
<Banner
  visible={true}
  style={{
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }}>
  <Text style={{}} variant="bodyMedium">
    item 1
  </Text>
  <Text style={{}} variant="bodyMedium">
    item 2
  </Text>
  <Text style={{}} variant="bodyMedium">
    item 3
  </Text>
</Banner>
```

What's also strange is that if I give the child `Text` elements `width: 33%` nothing changes either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Absolutely this has to work. Because, its working for me. But unfortunately I can't identify the issue with the provided info. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: remove `display: 'flex'` and use `flex:1`

Answer (score 0):

By setting the flex property to 1 for each  component will make them take up equal space and align them centrally within the  component. Setting the textAlign property to 'center' to horizontally align the text within each  component.

```
<Banner
  visible={true}
  style={{
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }}>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: 'center' }} variant="bodyMedium">
    item 1
  </Text>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: 'center' }} variant="bodyMedium">
    item 2
  </Text>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: 'center' }} variant="bodyMedium">
    item 3
  </Text>
</Banner>
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Try using a different element like <span> and see if that works... React components may use different rendering that may conflict and you will have to use a different approach, such as passing additional props or using a different component, to achieve the desired styling.  See if you can find check the documentation or implementation of the <Banner> component or the library it belongs to.

Comment: > Text strings must be rendered within a `<Text> component.

Comment: You are right that changing from `Banner` to `View` fixes it, but not sure how to override the banner css